# 301 redirect isn't working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog that I'm trying to redirect to a different domain.

- Old domain: `http://harrisonfjord.com`
- New domain: `http://agoodman.com/blog/`

Google states that you should do 301 redirection for all pages, so I took a list of urls from my XML sitemap and just manually set up the redirection.

Here's what I've put in my .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/PkKNbJKf

The file structure is the same across both domains, so I can simply redirect each page as follows:

```
redirect 301 http://harrisonfjord.com/ http://agoodman.com.au

redirect 301 http://harrisonfjord.com/whatever http://agoodman.com.au/blog/whatever
```

However, this currently isn't working. Do I need to put the redirection in an  tag or something?

Comment: Is the redirect happening at all? If not, then check that Apache's honoring .htaccess in that directory.

Comment: Nope, no redirects are happening at all. About to show my ignorance - how do I check this? In cpanel?

Comment: `AllowOverride None` completely disables .htaccess files. Check if that's active in whatever dir you've got the .htaccess

Comment: Quite possible that this is the case, although I can't find the apache settings on my server. Should I be looking for /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf ? There's no /usr/ directory that I can see. Can I check this in cpanel?

Comment: standard apache conf file is in /etc somewhere, but no idea how your machine is configured.

Comment: Ah, according to A Small Orange I don't have access to httpd.conf as I'm on a shared server. The redirects are all showing up in cpanel though (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/CFOKl.png ) so it looks like it's being ignored?

Comment: Yeah, if the htaccess was being processed, then you'd get at least SOMETHING ocurring - either a redirect, or a 500 internal error if redirects weren't allow under the current override settings.

Comment: Hi @MarcB, got it working on my server. However, the specific `redirect 301 domain1.com domain2.com` rules don't work at all, only RewriteEngine rules (but I only need specific pages redirected, NOT everything). Can you see the answer/comments below to help?

Comment: redirects don't include hostnames in the source. it'd be something like `<virtualhost domain1.com>redirectpermanent / domain2.com</virtualhost>`

Answer (score 1):

What if you redirect your old-domain to new new domain completely?

```
# redirect an entire site via 301
redirect 301 / http://agoodman.com/blog/
```

Also try using `RewriteEngine` as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://agoodman.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok, server problems are fixed. Your code ALMOST fixes the redirection issue; `site1.com/whatever` is redirecting to `site2.com/blog/whatever`. HOWEVER, I also need to set a one-page redirection from `site1.com` to `site2.com`, as site2 has a landing page that explains the new domain name. How do I add that in?

Comment: Second addendum @Asif: Your rule also makes "agoodman.com.au" redirect to "agoodman.com.au/blog/agoodman.com.au"!

Comment: @Jascination for the second addendum: I think you have put the same `.htaccess` in your `http://agoodman.com/` also..Its only to be placed in your `old-domain`...and for first, See your own question's second and third line, the code is according to the info you have provided, i.e., to redirect `site1.com/` to `site2.com/blog/`.